# How to play my video using ember application in my website

Tags: ember.js

In my ember application i have installes videojs using
npm install --save-dev video.js
bower install video.js

in my hbs code is:

To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
                                      supports HTML5 video

javascript  code is:
var player = videojs('my-player');

var options = {};

var player = videojs('my-player', options, function onPlayerReady() {

videojs.log('Your player is ready!');

this.play();

this.on('ended', function() {

```
videojs.log('Awww...over so soon?!');
```

});

});

how to add this javascript code in controllers..

Comment: Please provide more information on what problem you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

There is an Ember addon for videojs https://github.com/IvyApp/ivy-videojs

Perhaps consider using that?

Install:

`ember install ivy-videojs`

Template:

```
{{ivy-videojs
  canplay='canplay'
  controls=true
  ended='ended'
  fluid=true
  pause='pause'
  playing='playing'
  src=src}}
```

Controller:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  src: 'http://jell.yfish.us/media/jellyfish-3-mbps-hd-h264.mkv',
  controls: true,

  actions: {
    canplay() {
      console.log('video ready');
    },

    ended() {
      console.log('video ended'); 
    },

    pause() {
      console.log('video is paused');
    },

    playing() {
      console.log('video is playing');
    }
  }
});
```

[Ember Twiddle example](https://ember-twiddle.com/0030d0d3e14f58cd61c1cb7052965037?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C)